# How to override `Model.__init__` and respect `.using(db)` in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, orm, using

I have the following code:

```
print(f"current database: {self.db}\ninfusate from database: {infusate._state.db}\ntracer from database: {tracer._state.db}")
FCirc.objects.using(self.db).get_or_create(
    serum_sample=sample,
    tracer=tracer,
    element=label.element,
)
```

That is producing the following output and exception:

```
current database: validation
infusate from database: validation
tracer from database: validation
Validating FCirc updater: {'update_function': 'is_last_serum_peak_group', 'update_field': 'is_last', 'parent_field': 'serum_sample', 'child_fields': [], 'update_label': 'fcirc_calcs', 'generation': 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 581, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
DataRepo.models.fcirc.FCirc.DoesNotExist: FCirc matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/views/loading/validation.py", line 91, in validate_load_files
    call_command(
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/management/commands/load_animals_and_samples.py", line 134, in handle
    loader.load_sample_table(
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/utils/sample_table_loader.py", line 426, in load_sample_table
    FCirc.objects.using(self.db).get_or_create(
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    return self.create(**params), True
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 451, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/DataRepo/models/maintained_model.py", line 430, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 485, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Users/rleach/PROJECT-local/TRACEBASE/tracebase/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 229, in __set__
    raise ValueError('Cannot assign "%r": the current database router prevents relation between database "%s" and "%s".' % (value, instance._state.db, value._state.db))
ValueError: Cannot assign "<Tracer: lysine-[13C6]>": the current database router prevents this relation.
Cannot assign "<Tracer: lysine-[13C6]>": the current database router prevents this relation.
```

Knowing that this error relates to foreign relations between records in different databases, as a sanity check, I modified the source of `related_descriptors.py` to include more info:

```
raise ValueError('Cannot assign "%r": the current database router prevents relations between database "%s" and "%s".' % (value, instance._state.db, value._state.db))
```

And that prints:

```
Cannot assign "<Tracer: lysine-[13C6]>": the current database router prevents relations between database "default" and "validation".
```

So I was going nuts.  Why is it ignoring my `.using(self.db)` call?!

Then I realized, "Oh yeah - I over-rode `__init__` in the superclass to FCirc!  I'm probably circumventing `using(db)`.":

```
class FCirc(MaintainedModel, HierCachedModel):
    ...


class MaintainedModel(Model):
    ...
```

Out of the 2 superclass mixes, `MaintainedModel` seems to be the culprit in this case.  It's the only one that overrides `__init__`.  That override looks like this:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This over-ride of the constructor is to prevent developers from explicitly setting values for automatically
        maintained fields.  It also performs a one-time validation check of the updater_dicts.
        """

        # ... about 80 lines of code that I'm very confident are unrelated to the problem.  See the docstring above.  Will paste upon request ...

        # vvv THIS LINE IS LINE 430 FROM maintained_model.py IN THE TRACE ABOVE
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

How do I pass along self.db in the super constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Another developer had added calls to `full_clean` ([which I have a separate question about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930070/how-to-use-djangos-full-clean-using-a-non-default-database)) in derived classes of the `QuerySet` class for a few of the models.  E.g.:

```
class TracerQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    ...

class Tracer(MaintainedModel):
    objects = TracerQuerySet().as_manager()
    ...
```

Those calls to `full_clean` *appear* to only work on the default database.  At least, I haven't been able to figure out how to tell `full_clean` to operate on our validation database.

I changed the 3 or 4 calls I found `QuerySet` derived classes to only call `full_clean` if the current database is the default database:

```
if self._db == settings.DEFAULT_DB:
    tracer.full_clean()
```

After that, I no longer get the exception on the `FCirc` `get_or_create` call and the database operated on is the validation database.

I was curious though if I had any other database operations that were being assigned to the default database, so I added a debug print to another piece of code in `django.db.utils.py: _router_func`:

```
def _router_func(action):
    def _route_db(self, model, **hints):
        chosen_db = None
        for router in self.routers:
            try:
                method = getattr(router, action)
            except AttributeError:
                # If the router doesn't have a method, skip to the next one.
                pass
            else:
                chosen_db = method(model, **hints)
                if chosen_db:
                    return chosen_db
        instance = hints.get('instance')
        if instance is not None and instance._state.db:
            return instance._state.db

        ###
        ### See what code is getting the default database
        ###
        print(f"Returning default database.  Trace:")
        traceback.print_stack()

        return DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
    return _route_db
```

That revealed 2 other places that were querying the default database when I knew it should only be querying the validation database.

This one made sense, because it's a fresh database query:

```
def tracer_labeled_elements(self):
    """
    This method returns a unique list of the labeled elements that exist among the tracers.
    """
    from DataRepo.models.tracer_label import TracerLabel
    return list(
        TracerLabel.objects.filter(tracer__infusates__id=self.id)
        .order_by("element")
        .distinct("element")
        .values_list("element", flat=True)
    )
```

So I modified it to use the current database (based on the instance) instead:

```
def tracer_labeled_elements(self):
    """
    This method returns a unique list of the labeled elements that exist among the tracers.
    """
    from DataRepo.models.tracer_label import TracerLabel
    db = self.get_using_db()
    return list(
        TracerLabel.objects.using(db).filter(tracer__infusates__id=self.id)
        .order_by("element")
        .distinct("element")
        .values_list("element", flat=True)
    )
```

And I added this to my MaintainedModel class:

```
def get_using_db(self):
    """
    If an instance method makes an unrelated database query and a specific database is currently in use, this
    method will return that database to be used in the fresh query's `.using()` call.  Otherwise, django's code
    base will set the ModelState to the default database, which may differ from where the current model object came
    from.
    """
    db = settings.DEFAULT_DB
    if hasattr(self, "_state") and hasattr(self._state, "db"):
        db = self._state.db
    return db
```

That works, however I don't like that it requires the developer to include code in the derived class specific to the super class.  Plus, `settings.DEFAULT_DB` is project-specific, so it creates an inter-dependency.

What I really need to do is change the default database that the django base code sets when no database is explicitly specified...

My bet is that that's easy to do.  I've just never done it before.  I'll start looking into that and I'll probably edit this answer again soon.

### Previous "answer"

Alright, this is not really an answer, because I don't want developers to have to jump through these ridiculous hoops to use get_or_create on a model that inherits from `MaintainedModel`, but it solves the problem.  It prevents the exception and everything is applied to the correct database.

Maybe this will give someone else a hint as to how to correctly solve the problem inside the override of the `__init__` constructor in MaintainedModel:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelState
ms = ModelState
setattr(ms, "db", self.db)
print(f"current database: {self.db}\ninfusate from database: {infusate._state.db}\ntracer from database: {tracer._state.db}\nsample from database: {sample._state.db}\n_state type: {type(tracer._state)} db type: {type(tracer._state.db)}")
using_obj = FCirc.objects.using(self.db)
setattr(using_obj, "_state", ms)
print(f"using_obj database: {using_obj._state.db}")
using_obj.get_or_create(
    serum_sample=sample,
    tracer=tracer,
    element=label.element,
)
```

The output is:

```
current database: validation
infusate from database: validation
tracer from database: validation
sample from database: validation
_state type: <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelState'> db type: <class 'str'>
using_obj database: validation
```

Comment: Looks like I need to define custom database routers. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers